# Normal Order Reduction - is Leftmost Outermost order simply Leftmost?

Tags: lambda-calculus

This is a quick question.  I've been reading up on Lambda Calculus, and I see Normal Order as "outermost leftmost first", and Applicative Order described as as "innermost leftmost first".

I *think* this makes sense to me, but the explanation is often accompanied by a diagram of a tree (such as pages 15-17 in [this document](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~sedwards/classes/2018/4115-fall/lambda.pdf)), and I am unclear about why that would be needed.

Is it the case that the first application in Normal Order will always be the leftmost lambda symbol within the lambda string?  (This presuming that there is something to apply to this lambda.  If not, we would simply move on to the next one, from left to right.)

Comment: Yes, you are right :)

Comment: @ApoorvIngle Thank you!